# django contains all query

Tags: django, django-orm

I have some models like that;

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through='RecipeIngredient')

class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
```

How can I find the recipes that contains all Ingredients?

Here is an example;

```
>>> i1 = Ingredient(name="egg")
>>> i1.save()
>>> i2 = Ingredient(name="flour")
>>> i2.save()
>>> i3 = Ingredient(name="water")
>>> i3.save()
>>> i4 = Ingredient(name="milk")
>>> i4.save()
>>> i5 = Ingredient(name="sugar")
>>> i5.save()
>>> i6 = Ingredient(name="carrot")
>>> i6.save()
>>> i7 = Ingredient(name="wheat")
>>> i7.save()

>>> r1 = Recipe(name="omelet")
>>> r1.save()
>>> r1.ingredients.add(i1, i2, i3)
>>> r2 = Recipe(name="icecream")
>>> r2.save()
>>> r2.ingredients.add(i3, i4, i5)

>>> test = Recipe.objects.filter(ingredients__in=[i1.id, i2.id, i3.id, i4.id])
>>> test
[<Recipe: omelet>, <Recipe: omelet>, <Recipe: omelet>, <Recipe: icecream>, <Recipe: icecream>]
```

I want to find only omelet. Because only omelet contains egg (i1), flour (i2), water (i3)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe chain it together?

```
Recipe.objects.filter(ingredients=i1.id).filter(ingredients=i2.id).filter(ingredients=i3.id).filter(ingredients=i4.id)
```

Comment: >>> Recipe.objects.filter(ingredients=i1.id).filter(ingredients=i2.id).filter(ingredients=i3.id).filter(ingredients=i4.id)
[]